# adding image to tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter. I want to create a GUI that can support embedding audio files and that also has a background image. I have tried endlessly to install pygame to no avail. I cannot seem to figure out why it is not installing correctly so at this point I am just trying to find the easiest way possible to have these two options. Below is my attempt at displaying a background image using a canvas widget. However, I always get an error that my variables are not defined. I would really appreciate some feedback on what I am doing wrong, as well as any helpful tkinter tutorials that involve more than just the basics. Thanks in advance

```
from Tkinter import *   

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        #initialize the frame
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.can = Canvas(root, width=160, height=160, bg='white')
        self.pic = PhotoImage(file='speaker.gif')
        self.item = can.create_image(80, 80, image=pic)

app = Application(root)

#kick off event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you want to use an attribute of a class inside one of its methods, you need to prefix it with `self.`:

```
self.item = self.can.create_image(80, 80, image=self.pic)
#           ^^^^^                               ^^^^^
```

Otherwise, Python will treat the names as being local to the function and will raise an exception when it fails to find them.

Also, you forgot to call `grid` on your canvas widget:

```
self.can = Canvas(root, width=160, height=160, bg='white')
self.can.grid(...)
```

---

As for resources on Tkinter, you can check out these:

- http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/onepage.html
- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/