# Embedding a tkinter image into a Toplevel

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I want to add an image to a topframe in `tkinter`. It works on the `MainMenu`, but not on the `SideMenu`. When run, it should show _test.gif on the first menu, and when the button is pressed, open the second menu and show _test2.gif. Currently, the second menu is blank - no image.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainMenu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.launch_MainMenu()
    def launch_MainMenu(self):
        self._mainMenuWindow = tk.Tk()
        self.imageGIF = tk.PhotoImage(file="_test.gif");
        self.imageLabel = tk.Label(self._mainMenuWindow,image=self.imageGIF)
        self.imageLabel.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
        tk.Button(self._mainMenuWindow,text="Next Menu",
                  command=SideMenu).grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10)
        tk.mainloop()

class SideMenu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.launch_sideMenu()
    def launch_sideMenu(self):
        self._sideWindow = tk.Toplevel()
        self.imageGIF2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="_test2.gif")
        self.imageLabel2 = tk.Label(self._sideWindow,image=self.imageGIF2)
        self.imageLabel2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: This [adding image to tkinter gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049315/adding-image-to-tkinter-gui) will be of help to your question. You will need to add "self." Before the local variable(imageXxx).

Comment: @kunif: I thought that at first, too, but it's not the problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified my original code. It's 2 different images.

Comment: The variable of MainMenu class is not preceded by "self.".
And, is it better for initialie Tk() and mainloop to be outside the MainMenu class? .

Comment: Thank you for your advice kunif. I've added self. to everything in the mainmenu, but the second image is still not showing. Could you offer some more help please?

Comment: Is [the answer to this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115378/tkinter-example-code-for-multiple-windows-why-wont-buttons-load-correctly) close to what you want to do?  
If so, you should add an image display process to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes will make it work. A new method named `add_sidemenu()` has been added to class `MainMenu` and it is used as the value of the `command=` argument passed to the `Button` widget when it's being created.

In the new method it creates and *saves* a `SideMenu` instance. In your code this instance was getting deleted almost as soon as the it was created because it's not stored in variable. I also did the something similar with both the `tk.PhotoImage` instances—even it's not strictly necessary for the one in `MainMenu` because the `tk.mainloop()` call at the end of `launch_MainMenu()` prevents the local variable it's in from going out of scope too soon (so it's not deleted while it's still needed). I did it anyway, because that's generally a good practive to do it with **all** images used in `tkinter` (and folks not doing that is a big part of the reason there's so many related questions here).

I also tried to reformat your code so it follows [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) more closely. I strongly suggest you read and start following the guidelines in—your code will easier for other (and you) to read (as well as easing debugging and maintainence).

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainMenu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.launch_MainMenu()

    def launch_MainMenu(self):
        self._mainMenuWindow = tk.Tk()
        self.imageGIF = tk.PhotoImage(file="_test.gif");
        imageLabel = tk.Label(self._mainMenuWindow, image=self.imageGIF)
        imageLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        tk.Button(self._mainMenuWindow, text="Next Menu",
                  command=self.add_sidemenu).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
        tk.mainloop()

    def add_sidemenu(self):
        self.sidemanu = SideMenu()
        self.sidemanu.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)

class SideMenu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.launch_sideMenu()

    def launch_sideMenu(self):
        self._sideWindow = tk.Toplevel()
        self.imageGIF2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="_test2.gif")
        self.imageLabel2 = tk.Label(self._sideWindow, image=self.imageGIF2)
        self.imageLabel2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

mainMenu = MainMenu()
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much for stopping by to help me. The program I'm making is to help someone help other people who really needs it, and I am back on the road to finishing it! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to python's garbage collector. You're not keeping a reference to the instance of `SideMenu` so it's getting garbage-collected.

Due to a quirk of how tkinter is implemented, that causes the image object to be destroyed even though the widget itself is not destroyed.

It's *highly* unusual to have the target of a button be a class. Instead, create a proper function that creates an instance of `SideMenu`, and saves a reference to that object.

```
class MainMenu(object):
    ...
    def launch_ManMenu(self):
        ...
        tk.Button(..., command=self.sidemenu, ...)

    def sidemenu(self):
        self.sidemenu = SideMenu()
```

You also need to keep a reference of the image in `SideMenu`, just like you do in `MainMenu`:

```
class SideMenu(object):
    ...
    def launch_sideMenu(self):
        ...
        self.my_image = tk.PhotoImage(...)
        myCanvas.create_image(..., image=self.my_image)
        ...
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much for stopping by to help me. The program I'm making is to help someone help other people who really needs it, and I am back on the road to finishing it! Have a great day! I so wish I could green tick this answer as well!